# Вставить ячейку в таблицу

Tags: objective-c, xcode7, ios8

Необходимо в UItableView с уже существующими ячейками, вставить ячейку в центр. (Например существует 4 ячейки в таблице надо после второй вставить новую)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По крайней мере есть два простых способа решения этой задачи. Первый, самый простой, если у вас есть массив, по которым строятся ячейки, то Вам в это массив просто нужно добавить еще один элемент, а потом вызвать `[tableView reloadData]`. Есть и второй способ, который красиво сделает вставление, это использование метода таблицы `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`. Ну и третий способ, который тоже имеет место быть,

```
 [self.tableView beginUpdates];
 [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPathOfYourCell] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
 [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

и выбираете анимацию, с которой хотите добавлять ячейки. Это вам три простейших способа, добавления ячеек, для начала вам этого хватит с головой.

Comment: огромное спасибо !!